# jQuery 'text' not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
var $insertSuccessMessage = $('#insertSuccessMessage');
var $successPopup = $('#successPopup');
var $successSpan = $('#successSpan');
```

I have a div tag:

```
<div id="insertSuccessMessage"></div>
```

When a user successfully enters a value into an input field, I am trying to get a 'success' popup to appear beneath this div tag like so:

```
$insertSuccessMessage.append('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" id='successPopup' role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><span id="successSpan"></span></div>');
$successSpan.text("Successfully inserted value!");
```

Side: I'm using Bootstrap.

So the `successPopup` will appear, but the text won't; the text is not inserted in between the span tags.

Comment: You need to provide significantly more code for us to help you with this problem. successSpan is undefined as far as I can tell.

Comment: You have an error in your code, mixing single and double quotes.  On your line starting with `$insertSuccessMessage.append...` the part `id='successPopup'` should be written in double quotes. With single quotes it escapes the string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You aren't defining `$successSpan`. You need to use `$('#successSpan')` to access the element by ID

**Update after your edit:**

You are defining `$successSpan` too early. When you define it, the `#successSpan` element doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Right but how would he be accessing insertSuccessMessage in the first place?

Comment: Yup, you are right. I added the variable `$successSpan` after `.append` line. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$insertSuccessMessage.append('
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" id='successPopup' role="alert">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><span id="successSpan">
</span></div>');
$successSpan.text("Successfully inserted value!");
```

you're breaking the string by using an unescaped apostrophe when defining the id attribute on successPopup.

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" id='successPopup' role="alert">
```

should be

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" id="successPopup" role="alert">
```

or alternatively

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" id=\'successPopup\' role="alert">
```

Answer (score 1):

Does `#successSpan` element exist in the `DOM` before you try to refer to it? After appending `#successSpan` to `#insertSuccessMessage`, you should be able to refer to `#successSpan` like this:

```
$('#successSpan').text("Successfully inserted value!");
```

Comment: Yeah, that was my problem. I was referring to the element before it existed in the DOM. It has been fixed now and is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this modification

```
$insertSuccessMessage.append('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" id="successPopup" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><span id="successSpan"></span></div>');
$('#successSpan').text("Successfully inserted value!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string selector.

Try this:

```
$('#insertSuccessMessage').append('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" id="successPopup" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><span id="successSpan"></span></div>');
$('#successSpan').html("Successfully inserted value!");
```

Here is work fine!